# The set of values of a parameter so equation has solution

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

Find $m$ so that the equation has real solution:

$$\cos^2 x + (m+1) \sin x = 2m - 1$$

This can be rewritten as

$$2 \sin^2 x - (m+1) \sin x +2m - 2 = 0$$

A first condition would be the discriminant $\Delta \ge 0$, from which I got that $m \in (-\infty, 7-4 \sqrt{2}] \cup [7 + 4 \sqrt{2}, + \infty)$.

Also, the minimum point of the function should be in $[-1, 1]$, so another condition would be $\frac{m+1}{2} \in [-1, 1]$. What else should I impose ?

The correct answer is $ m \in [0, 2]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must solve the equation
$$\sin(x)^2-(m+1)\sin(x)+2m-2=0$$
we have exactly two real Solutions namely $2$ or $$m-1$$
can you finish?
and we have $$-1\le m-1\le 1$$

Comment: Thank you. I just added an extra $2$ at $\sin(x)^2$...